# Reopen accepted change in Gerrit

Tags: git, branch, gerrit, git-push

A previous code that I sent into Gerrit was accepted and merged into the master branch, but it turned out that the solution was not cost effective enough so I had to modify it. It is now ready again so I wanted to push it into Gerrit on the same feature branch but I get the following error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 175 closed)
```

Is there a way to reopen a change or how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a new local branch and migrate my changes to the new branch then I managed to push the changes.

Comment: The change was closed and your commit had the same Change-Id.

Comment: In the output of the git log command the commits had different change-ids.